# Describing the best attainment in someone's progress: Is "what I mostly pleased by with regard to his progress" okay?

Tags: phrase-request

> Jack's sense of rhythm has improved a lot over this year, and his
>   improvisation technics have increased, too. However, **what I mostly
>   pleased by with regard to his progress is** his ability to keep the
>   pitch. If before he would slide within one second, now he can stay on
>   one note for quite a long time. I consider it to be his best
>   attainment this year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrasing used in this sentence is kind of silly sounding and not correct, if you want to say that you're pleased with the progress made by an individual, you could for example say:

> However, **what I was pleased by the most regarding his progress, is his** ability to keep the pitch.

or possibly

> However, **what pleased me the most regarding the progress he's made**, is his ability to keep the pitch.

the way you said it

> what I mostly pleased by with regard to his progress is

this sentence would require a "was" or "am" to make it sound decent and "with" doesn't go together with "by"

> What I was mostly pleased by in regard to his progress is,
>
> What I am mostly pleased by in regard to his progress is,

or you can skip the regard and say

> What I was/am mostly pleased by with his progress is

Answer (score 0):

We also say **stay on pitch** and **hold pitch**.  In your scenario, you could say

> What I'm most pleased about is that he's able to hold pitch.

[Example 1](https://books.google.com/books?id=cc_BAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA45&dq=%22hold%20pitch%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjJsr7yo73eAhXhnuAKHXx-DvEQ6AEISzAG#v=onepage&q=%22hold%20pitch%22&f=false).

[Example 2.](https://books.google.com/books?id=NyZ1pj_bVLcC&pg=PT91&dq=%22hold%20pitch%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjJsr7yo73eAhXhnuAKHXx-DvEQ6AEIVTAI#v=onepage&q=%22hold%20pitch%22&f=false)